# How do I load ascx pages faster in visual studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

One of my (my team's) biggest peeves with VS2008 is the slow speed in which ascx load. It could take up to a couple minutes to do something as simple as a text or style change simply because of the time it takes to load an ascx page into the visual studio text editor. Half the time I'm tempted to check out the file, edit it in notepad, then check it back in.

Is there any trick to speeding this up?

Comment: Can't say I've experienced this myself. Is the ascx in question very large/complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically right click the file and select view markup, so that it only has to load the text into the editor.

Other than that, faster hardware always works wonders.

Answer (score 0):

Not load directly from Design view, active HTML view by default in VS options.